# Spring Web Service SOAP is not working after integration with struts 2.3?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, action-mapping

Till now in my project the spring 3.0.1 and struts 2.0 was getting integrated and SOAP web service was working perfectly fine. But for some security reason I have migrated to struts 2.3 and for SOAP, I am using jars like spring-ws-all-1.5.9 and wsld4j-1.6.2.jar.

Still when I am calling my web service method I am getting exception like this:

HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [someServices] associated with context path [/someproject].

I tried to search the solution for this problem but I didn't get any. I finally migrated my jar to spring-ws-2.0.2.RELEASE-all.jar . Still I am getting the same problem. Please help me if anyone have any idea.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is the Struts setup, the filter is intercepting all requests and trying to handle them.

Comment: Post S2 configuration. Read migration guides: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-guide.html.